# oauth using G+ community group

Tags: openid-connect, google-plus-signin

I would like to know if its possible to use OpenID connect exclusively for a given Google Community.

So the site will only allow people from a given Google+ community to login, as opposed to anyone with a gmail account.

The benefit as I see is, user management can be done from the G+ community.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it indirectly - check the membership of the groups to which the user belongs, and allow him access only if he belongs to your group, else log them out.

Answer (score 0):

it needs to be implemented as an access control decision based on group membership obtained from Google, as part of the application that operates the OpenID Connect client